# getting most inner type object in one to many relation in linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, eager-loading

i'm very new to linq.i have 3 entities in DB

```
 TYPE, QUESTION,ANSWER
```

every type have many questions
every question have many answers,
i eagerly loaded IList, which have all question and answers, I need to fetch all of answers disregard its type and question, i mean i need to have result which its type is type Of ANSWER which have all of ANSWERS in DB.
 i have

```
IList<TYPE> types=context.TYPES.ToList();
```

but i dont have any idea about how to get all answers.

Comment: You use entity framework (EF)?

Comment: @daniel yes EF code first

Comment: Did these tables has foreign key relationship?

Comment: @daniel yes, they have relation with foreign key

Comment: I think **Include** should be helpful for your case. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: If you need all the answers disregard any other entity, why wouldn't `context.ANSWERS.ToList();` work ? If related entities are required, Includes should do the trick... Maybe I missed something...

Comment: @daniel i included answers and question

Comment: @xum59 the problem is in my method i use i get lists of types i dont want to pass another object or new context again

Comment: Then you can use **Where** to filter what you want and **Select** to return the final list. **Where** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338811%28v=vs.110%29.aspx **Select** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298787%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the "QUESTION" and "QUESTION.ANSWER" provide you the list by foreign key relationship.

```
IList<TYPE> types = context.TYPES.Include("QUESTION").Include("QUESTION.ANSWER").ToList();
```

To check

```
var questions = types.SelectMany(t => t.QUESTION).ToList();
var answers = questionList.SelectMany(t => t.ANSWER).ToList();
```

But I think you should do this directly.

```
IList<QUESTION> questions = context.QUESTION.Include("TYPE").Include("ANSWER").ToList();
```

Comment: tnx for reply, but the problem is first() will give the first type questions, i'm trying with foreach loop. meybe the only way

Comment: You want aggregate question or answer in a list? If yes, question or answer? There is other elegant way to do this instead of foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your question, you want to obtain all the answers from a retrieved `IList<TYPE>`.

First, you have to include all subtypes in your DB Query :

```
allTypes = db.TYPES.Include("QUESTIONS").Include("QUESTIONS.ANSWERS").ToList();
```

And then, just flatten the hierarchy with the `SelectMany` LinQ method :

```
var items = allTypes.SelectMany(t => t.QUESTIONS.SelectMany(a => a.ANSWERS));
```

By then, you should be able to iterate through all the answers (and do whatever needed with their related entities)

Comment: i tried to upvote, but because of reputation i cant, thanks this works correctly also.